# How to add resource for module in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, bootstrapping

I have a test module.

I have a class in **myproject/application/modules/test/lists/Profiles.php**

```
class Test_List_Profiles {
    // class members    
}
```

Now when I access this class in **myproject/application/modules/test/controllers/ProfileController.php**

```
public function indexAction() {
   $profilesList = new Test_List_Profiles();
}
```

It gives me following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test_List_Profiles' not found
```

I have following entry in **Bootstrap.php** as well:

```
protected function _initAutoload() {

  $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

  $testModuleLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . 'modules/test',
            'namespace' => 'Test_',
            'resourceTypes' => array( 'form' => array( 'path'=>'forms/', 'namespace'=>'Form_' ),
                                      'list' => array( 'path'=>'lists/', 'namespace'=>'List_' )  
                                    )
        ));           
}
```

How to access **Test_List_Profiles** class everywhere in project ?

Thanks

Comment: where Notification_List_Notifications is defined?

Comment: @zeeshan: It was spelling mistake. Please review the question again..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to add your list resource in the test module bootstrap class (myproject/application/modules/test/Bootstrap.php) this way:

```
class Test_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initAutoload(){

        $autoloader = $this->getResourceLoader();

        $autoloader->addResourceType('list', 'models/lists', 'Model_List');

        return $autoloader;

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. This is also a way but I have also find my mistake in my bootstrap.php. Check out my answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was error in basePath path. A slash(/) was missing.

```
protected function _initAutoload() {

  $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

  $testModuleLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/test',
            'namespace' => 'Test_',
            'resourceTypes' => array( 'form' => array( 'path'=>'forms/', 'namespace'=>'Form_' ),
                                      'list' => array( 'path'=>'lists/', 'namespace'=>'List_' )  
                                    )
        ));           
}
```

It is working now.